# Change Android Emulator's Language on Android 6.0 and 7.0

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the language on an Android version 6.0 (or greater) emulator through the adb shell. The first change works but the next one doesn't.
On Android 5.0 it works fine -> I was able to change the language more than once.

The commands I use in order to change the language are:

1. adb shell
2. setprop persist.sys.language [XX]
3. setprop persist.sys.country [XX]
4. stop
5. start

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: any error or stacktrace?

Comment: When the emulator starts again (after the second language change) there is a popUp that says "Unfortunately, Launcher3 has stopped."

Comment: and no messages in stack trace either?

Comment: How can I get the stacktrace of the core?

Comment: by core I mean Android's OS